# Using regex to find a pattern and then replace with fillers and pushing all the digits at the end

Tags: regex, pyspark, replace

I am using regex function. I have some unique numbers that I am trying to replace with some characters to increase the match between two variables. See one of my example below.

The example: I want `APKC3475` to be replaced by `AK113475`. In order to do that I am using the following regex code:

```
df = df.withColumn('columnname',regexp_replace('columnname', '^APKC', 'AK11'))
```

By using this code it will replace all similar unique numbers that starts with `APKC` to `AK11` and retains the last four characters as it is.

I want to generate a similar regex code for a unique number `QT156UOE` which should be converted to `QT111156`. Another similar example is `QT265UOE` to be converted to `QT111265`.

Basically, I want to convert the format of the unique numbers from `QTXXXUOE` to `QT111XXX`, where `XXX` represents the last three digits of the original number. Can someone please help with the regex code for it, preferably using PySpark.

I tried the below solution:

```
df = df.withColumn('columnname',regexp_replace('columnname', '^QT...UOE', 'QT111...'))
```

It is not working. May be it is a silly question but I just started to learn coding one month before. Thank you for your patience and support.

Comment: Use a capture group in the regexp, and a back-reference in the replacement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following: (https://regex101.com/r/8my927/1)

```py
df = df.withColumn('columnname',regexp_replace('columnname', '^QT(...)UOE', 'QT111\1'))
```

The brackets in `^QT(...)...` store the contents of the first 3 characters after QT into `\1`. Then `QT111\1` places those saved characters at the end of the ID after QT111.

Comment: Thank you @EDD, but the problem is it is replacing even the unique numbers that do not ends with 'UOE'.

Comment: @newbee23 if it must end with `UOE` then you can change `^QT(...)...` to `^QT(...)UOE`.

Comment: I am not sure if I can ask you here @EDD. I was trying to use Regex and Replace to match it with a different column. Now, I want the 'replace code' to change if it doesn't match with the other column by using a nested loop. For example if ^QT(...)UOE, 'QT111\1' is not equal to any values in 'new_unique_code' then ^QT(...)UOE replaced by NP111\1 and like this a couple of more combinations until it matches with any value in 'new_unique code'. Can you please help me with the syntax?

Comment: @newbee23 Im not sure about the library youre using so Im not entirely sure but regexes cant do everything. For a more complex replacement I would recommend not using regex because they get quite hard to read when doing something complicated.